# How to read pixel values for Raw Image on Android

Tags: android, image-processing, dng

I have managed to capture a RAW image on Android and save it to disk as a DNG. What I want to do is read the raw sensor data of each "pixel" for the image. Specifically, I just want to read the green sensor values before any processing. What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Do you want to process the image on the Android device, or transfer it to a computer and process it there? The [android] and [javax.imageio] tags are mutually exclusive...

Comment: I want to process it on the Android device. I didn't know that thanks.